# C++ methods for network protocol parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, binary, network-protocols

I am looking for a good strategy people use in C++/C to parse complex binary network protocols (such as DNS). Any tips and articles would be great.

Comment: Boost has a serialization class that I've heard is usable but I just wrote my own implementation with some templating/memcpy

Answer (score 1):

[Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) appears to support the types that Python `struct()` can handle.  It supports Python too.

> Welcome to the developer documentation
>   for protocol buffers – a
>   language-neutral, platform-neutral,
>   extensible way of serializing
>   structured data for use in
>   communications protocols, data
>   storage, and more.